# Unable to login due to invalid screen resolution

Tags: ubuntu, xorg, resolution

I changed the screen resolution on Ubuntu 12.08 using the GUI, but I think I've changed it to an unsupported resolution, and now the system logs me out immediately after I login. I tried using `xrandr` to fix it, but haven't had any progress yet. I can log in with the guest account though

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Please upload the contents of `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` and the contents of `.xsession-errors` in your home directory after a failed login attempt.

Comment: do you mean 12.04 LTS or Quantal alpha?